# creating record in salesforce

Tags: php, salesforce

I am trying to create a record in Salesforce Enterprise but I get an error message.

The code:

```
<?php

define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once ('userAuth.php');

try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
  $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

  $sObject1 = new stdclass();
  $sObject1->number__c = '20';
  $sObject1->name__c = 'testupdateCity';
  $sObject1->country__c = 'US';

  $response = $mySforceConnection->update(array ($sObject1), 'nisaion_01__c');

  print_r($response);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  print_r($mySforceConnection->getLastRequest());
  echo $e->faultstring;
}
?>
```

---

The error:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Id not specified in an update call [statusCode] => MISSING_ARGUMENT ) ) [id] => [success] => ) )

---

What do I do wrong?

Comment: best to ask this on:http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I asked in salesforce.stackexchange.com and got a good reply.

Comment: probably best to delete this one, the other will be good for reference  as it has an answer this one does not.